# footerview list Api26

Tags: java, android, listview, casting

in my Fragment i have a ListView AND I WANT TO ADD FOOTERVIEW i have tested with api 21 it's working but no with api26 !!

```
View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list, container, false);

    loadView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.footer,container,false);
```

So when i scroll in the and of the List

```
listview.addFooterView(View);
```

i have error

```
 android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.AbsListView$LayoutParams
                  at android.widget.ListView.removeUnusedFixedViews(ListView.java:2135)
```

there is my View footer xml file

```
<ProgressBar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    />
```

Comment: Do you have anything in your code that uses `LayoutParams`?

Comment: It would be helpful to see a little more of the code that surrounds your call to `addFooterView()`. I know you included some lines in your original question, but seeing everything together might help.